# Are all sine functions odd?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry

If I have a function like : $f(x) = \sin(e^{x/2} + e^{-x/2})$ or something equally complicated, do I actually need to work out if $f(-x) = -f(x)$, or are all sine functions odd no matter what it is a function of and it is just a matter of proving this using trig identities?

thanks!

Comment: Yes, you do; in point of fact composing on the right an odd function with a non-odd function may jeopardise the property entirely.

Comment: @pax that is incorrect: they actually behave like numbers *under multiplication*.

Comment: @pax, no the composition of two odd functions is odd. The composition of an even function with an even or odd function (in either order) is even. Try it out with powers of $x$.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime ah yes, that was a silly mistake. Thank you for point it out.

Answer (score 12):

No, not all $\sin(f(x))$ are odd. In fact, you need $f$ to be odd for that to happen.

Well, not exactly; the non-injectiveness of the sine function means there are other ways to make it happen. For instance, we can loosen the oddness requirement on $f$ to "for any $x$ there is an $n$ such that $f(-x)=2\pi n-f(x)$". And that's not the most loose construction. But we're getting close.

So if you insert, say, an *even* $f$ into the sine function, the result is necessarily an even function. For instance, $\sin((-x)^2)=\sin(x^2)$.

Answer (score 9):

No, and in fact the example you give is not odd but even.

If you have a function of the form $f(x)=g(h(x))$ and you only know $g$ is odd, that doesn't tell you much about $f$. If $h$ is also odd, then $f$ will be odd (because $h(-x)=-h(x)$ and so $g(h(-x))=g(-h(x))=-g(h(x))$). However, if $h$ is even (as here) then $f$ will also be even, and if $h$ is neither even nor odd then $f$ could be neither even nor odd.

Comment: And if $h$ is even, then $f$ is even, regardless of whether $g$ is even, odd, or neither.